# jQuery replace all HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to replace all the HTML (including the HTML tags) with another page. What I'm trying to do is having a website acting as an app even when navigating the another page.

Here is the code :

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.loadingPage = {
    attach: function(context,settings) {
      $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Create the loading icon
        // ...
        $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('href'),
          success: function(data) {
            $('html').replaceWith(data);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried several things. replaceWith() causes a jQuery error in jquery.js after deleting the HTML tag, I guess it is because it can't find the parent anymore to add the replacement.

The best result I got was with `document.write(data)`. The problem is, the javascript code on the loaded page is not executed.

Anyone got a better idea ?

Comment: Try replacing the contents of the `<html>` tag with the contents of data? It's not like `<html>` has any useful attributes.

Comment: That said, the only thing this will achieve is you impersonating the other page until the user clicks on a link on it.

Comment: @Sii if anything, it is holding the browser test results which you don't want to redo, because we are all using Modernizr right? :P

Comment: If you're reloading the whole page anyway, why are you doing it with ajax?  Just set `window.location` to the new URL, or POST a form if you need it to be a POST instead of a GET.

Comment: @Sii the data variable has the HTML tag in it, which is why I can't just replace it. Pointy : see my answer to nnnnnn below.

Comment: @Florian So get rid of the HTML tag.

Comment: @Florian I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better idea? Yeah, just load the new page normally by setting `window.location` instead of using AJAX. Or submit a form.

Otherwise, if you want to load something to replace all of the visible content of the current page but keep the current page's script going, put all the visible content in a frame sized to fill the browser window - which, again, you wouldn't populate using AJAX.

(I like AJAX, but I don't see why you'd use it to replace a whole page.)

Comment: as I stated in my first post (but badly, I guess), I'm trying to have my website acting as a real app, not a page in a browser. For this, I'm putting a "loading icon" while the _internal_ clicked link is loading. I'd just like to know *how* to do it :-). Using frames would allow me to do that? I just used AJAX because it's a way I thought.

Comment: As a completely subjective aside: single-page applications are incredibly annoying, and impersonating third-party sites more so (recall the DiggBar fiasco). Users of web apps expect navigating in an app to change pages, or at the very least URLs.

Comment: Also, yes, the canonical way to embed another webpage in yours is frames or iframes. Bear in mind that you can't access the content of them from your script if they come from another domain for security reasons.

Comment: To follow on from what Sii said, if it is all _your_ "application" coming from the same domain your frames can access each others' content (including calling functions defined in other frames, etc.). A frames tutorial is beyond the scope of an answer here though.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys for the answers :) @Sii : I do plan to change URLs using http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: You mean [`pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), Ajax Crawling is just a way how to get applications using it into Google's index.