# How to replace &nbsp with space or %20 in all the html pages at one go?

Tags: jquery, html

Can you all please let me know if there is any way to remove all the special characters & nbsp; with either space or "%20" in all the HREF's in all html pages of a website? Below is the code snippet that I am trying but in vain

```
$(function(){
               var corruptedUrls = $("a[href*='&nbsp;']");
         for(var url in corruptedUrls)
         {
           var urlHref = url.attr("href");
           var modifiedUrlHref = urlHref.replace("&nbsp;", "%20");
           url.attr("href", modifiedUrlHref );
          }

      });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620669/jquery-replace-all-html , maybe this helps you a little bit .

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\s` as a pattern to match whitespaces of any kind.
+ Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for looping thru elements
+ Use `/pattern/g`to a global match of [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
$(function() {
  var corruptedUrls = $("a[href*='\u00a0']");
  corruptedUrls.each(function() {
    var urlHref = $(this).attr("href");
    var modifiedUrlHref = encodeURIComponent(urlHref.replace(/\s/g, ' '));
    $(this).attr("href", modifiedUrlHref);
    $('#log').html(modifiedUrlHref);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="hello this is a url">a</a>
<a href="hello&nbsp;this&nbsp;is&nbsp;an&nbsp;other&nbsp;url">a</a>
<div>
result: <pre id="log"></pre>
</div>
```